# React router changes the url but not reload the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend

When I call move to project editors function, everything works fine and history passes me to the right component but when I call move to add remove users function or  move to algorithm results function, the url did change but the component doesn't load and I stay in the same component as I was and don't get any error.
I tried to pass history also in props but it didn't help.

Here are the functions:

```
function moveToProjectsEditors(){
        props.history.push("/editorsTabs",{umlEditorId:props.umlEditor,sqlEditorId:props.sqlEditor,nfrEditorId:props.nfrEditor,ahpEditorId:props.ahpEditor})
    }

    function moveToAddRemoveUsers(){
        props.history.push("/manageUsers",{projectId:props.projectId})
    }

    function moveToResults(){
        props.history.push("/algorithmResults",{projectId:props.projectId})
    }
```

Routes

```
<Route path={"/algorithmResults/:projectId?"}>
                <AlgorithmResult/>
            </Route>

            <Route path={"/manageUsers/:projectId?"}>
                <ManageProjectUsers/>
            </Route>

<Route path={"/editorsTabs/:umlEditorId?/:sqlEditorId?/:nfrEditorId?/:ahpEditorId?"} >
                <EditorsTabs />
            </Route>
```

Please help me.

Comment: It seems your routes and paths are written assuming the data is passed as part of the path as `match.params`, but the links are written assuming plain route paths and data being passed via route state on `location.state`. Pick one or the other and be consistent. Once you pick one or the other and fix the code, if you've still an issue then please update your question here with the new relevant code, details, and information.

Comment: Could you attach a code example because I didn't fully understand what do you mean. The editors tabs path works fine in the current way but other routes don't work. I also tried add in the links the path params as the user below suggested but it didn't help either.

Comment: By the way, I also tried to change the route and the path to be with no parameters at all and it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're not defining the path properly by looking at your routes they're expecting certain id and you're not defining it in your push parameters

```
function moveToProjectsEditors(){
        props.history.push(`/editorsTabs/${props.umlEditor}/${props.sqlEditor}/${props.nfrEditor}/${props.ahpEditor}`,{umlEditorId:props.umlEditor,sqlEditorId:props.sqlEditor,nfrEditorId:props.nfrEditor,ahpEditorId:props.ahpEditor})
    }

    function moveToAddRemoveUsers(){
        props.history.push(`/manageUsers/${props.projectId}`,{projectId:props.projectId})
    }

    function moveToResults(){
        props.history.push(`/algorithmResults/${props.projectId}`,{projectId:props.projectId})
    }
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it didn't work, I still cannot pass to the component I want in moveToAddRemoveUsers and moveToAlgoritmResults

Comment: can you tell me how youve defined the routes

Comment: What do you mean? I posted how I defined then under Route component

Answer (score 0):

It seems your routes and paths are written assuming the data is passed as part of the path as `match.params`, but the links are written assuming plain route paths and data being passed via route state on `location.state`. Pick one or the other and be consistent.

### Using `match.params`

- AlgorithmResult

  ```
  <Route path={"/algorithmResults/:projectId?"}>
    <AlgorithmResult/>
  </Route>
  ```

  Navigate to a path including the `projectId` parameter:

  ```
  function moveToResults(){
    props.history.push(`/algorithmResults/${props.projectId}`);
  }
  ```
- ManageProjectUsers

  ```
  <Route path={"/manageUsers/:projectId?"}>
    <ManageProjectUsers/>
  </Route>
  ```

  Navigate to a path including the `projectId` parameter:

  ```
  function moveToAddRemoveUsers(){
    props.history.push(`/manageUsers/${props.projectId}`);
  }
  ```
- EditorsTabs

  ```
  <Route path={"/editorsTabs/:umlEditorId?/:sqlEditorId?/:nfrEditorId?/:ahpEditorId?"}>
    <EditorsTabs />
  </Route>
  ```

  Navigate to a path including the `umlEditorId`, `sqlEditorId`, `nfrEditorId`, and `ahpEditorId` parameters.

  ```
  import { generatePath } from `react-router-dom`

  function moveToProjectsEditors(){
    props.history.push(generatePath(
      "/editorsTabs/:umlEditorId/:sqlEditorId/:nfrEditorId/:ahpEditorId",
      {
        umlEditorId: props.umlEditor,
        sqlEditorId: props.sqlEditor,
        nfrEditorId: props.nfrEditor,
        ahpEditorId: props.ahpEditor,
      }
    ));
  }
  ```

### Using route state

Routes:

```
<Route path="/algorithmResults" >
  <AlgorithmResult/>
</Route>
<Route path="/manageUsers" >
  <ManageProjectUsers/>
</Route>
<Route path="/editorsTabs" >
  <EditorsTabs />
</Route>
```

Links sending route state:

```
function moveToProjectsEditors(){
  props.history.push(
    "/editorsTabs",
    {
      umlEditorId: props.umlEditor,
      sqlEditorId: props.sqlEditor,
      nfrEditorId: props.nfrEditor,
      ahpEditorId: props.ahpEditor,
    },
  );
}

function moveToAddRemoveUsers(){
  props.history.push(
    "/manageUsers",
    { projectId: props.projectId },
  );
}

function moveToResults(){
  props.history.push(
    "/algorithmResults",
    { projectId: props.projectId },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with history object. I updated to React Router v6 and replaced history with navigate and it solved the problem.